# webView dynamic height issue

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have one webView, in which i am showing html text. I am counting webView height as given below.

```
int height = [[_webViewDesc stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"] integerValue];
```

WebView's actual body size is different then what i am getting. How to get actual height for webView.

Comment: where you are adding this method to get the height?

Comment: while allocationg webView.

Answer (score 3):

To get the height, your webview must be loaded with html string first. Give delegate property to your webview object and try to get height in below function

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    int height = [[_webViewDesc stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.offsetHeight;"] integerValue];
    NSLog(@"%d",height);
}
```

you can also use below method to get height of webview

```
NSLog(@"%f",_webViewDesc.scrollView.contentSize.height);
```

Comment: for this i have to reload all components after this webview. See, i have one view with imageView,webView, Buttons. so if i change height of webView from here then i need to reload all button after webView.

Comment: @Nirav - there is no other way to get the height of a webview content, you have to load it first.